# is google appengine datastore.get(key) consistent?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've read the consistency page on

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

now i know that for queries to be consistent you need to use ancestor queries.

What about single key? query for example:

Entity e = datastore.get(Key)

are they eventually consistent or strongly consistent?
please do cite references or links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a get with a specific key is always consistent.

The documentation isn't as clear about this as it could be, but a get is not a query: it's a simple lookup in what is basically a key-value store. That will always return the correct data. It is only queries that can be inconsistent, because they must be done against indexes and the index update can lag.

The only reference I can give you is to point out that get is discussed on the [Entities, Properties and Keys page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities) whereas data consistency is discussed on the [Datastore Queries page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. besides the key, are the other properties also strongly consistent? for example i updated my firstname then i did a datastore.get(key) will i get the updated version?

Comment: Yes, that's the point: `get` will always get you the full updated entity.

Comment: Thanks, read it completely as well. it seems that only queries can generate eventually consistent results.